# How to use nice command in python?

Tags: python, nice

How to use nice in python ?

I have a simple bash script:

```
nice -n 9 cp /var/tmp/1 /var/tmp/2
```

What will be python alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In pure Python, you can use [os.nice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.nice) and [shutil.copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) (or [shutil.copyfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) if you do not need to preserve file metadata):

```
import os
import shutil

os.nice(9)
shutil.copy('/var/tmp/1', '/var/tmp/2')
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, there's always `os.system`:

```
os.system("nice -n 9 cp /var/tmp/1 /var/tmp/2")
```

A nicer solution is to use `os.nice` with `preexec_fn`:

```
import subprocess, os
subprocess.Popen("cp /var/tmp/1 /var/tmp/2", shell=True, preexec_fn=lambda: os.nice(9))
```